# Unbiased estimate of log-likelihood of Markov bridge

Tags: sampling, likelihood, markov-process, unbiased-estimator

**Note:** I have cross-posted this question to [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4802892/60713).

I have the following problem I am trying to solve. I have a parametric family of "transition" distributions $p_\theta(x_{i+1}\mid x_i)$ and I am given a starting point $x_0$ and an end point $x_n$. I denote by $p_\theta(x_n\mid x_0)$ the probability of reaching $x_n$ starting from $x_0$ and performing $n$ steps, where this process is assumed to be Markovian. What I need is an unbiased estimate of $\partial_\theta\log p_\theta(x_n\mid x_0)$ (think e.g. for some SGD process).

My approach is as follows. First we have
\begin{align}
\partial_\theta\log p_\theta(x_n\mid x_0)=\frac{\partial_\theta p_\theta(x_n\mid x_0)}{p_\theta(x_n\mid x_0)}.
\end{align}
The numerator is given by
\begin{align}
\partial_\theta p_\theta(x_n\mid x_0)={}&\partial_\theta\int dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}\prod_{i=1}^np_\theta(x_i\mid x_{i-1})\\
={}&\int dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^n\big(\partial_\theta p_\theta(x_j\mid x_{j-1})\big)\prod_{i\neq j}p_\theta(x_i\mid x_{i-1})\\
={}&\int dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_\theta \log p_\theta(x_j\mid x_{j-1})\right)\prod_{i=1}^np_\theta(x_i\mid x_{i-1}).
\end{align}
The denominator is
$$p_\theta(x_n\mid x_0)=\int dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}\prod_{i=1}^np_\theta(x_i\mid x_{i-1}),$$
which acts to normalize $\tau(x_{0:n}):=\prod_{i=1}^np_\theta(x_i\mid x_{i-1})$ to a probability density over "paths" from $x_0$ to $x_n$. Thus, I can rewrite
$$\partial_\theta\log p_\theta(x_n\mid x_0)=\mathbb{E}_{x_{0:n}\sim\tau}\left[\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_\theta \log p_\theta(x_j\mid x_{j-1})\right].$$
Therefore, the only thing left to do is drawing one or more samples from $\tau$. This could be done by some kind of Metropolis-Hastings sampling, but I am hoping in something faster to compute. My idea would be to draw a certain number $L$ of sequences $x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ from $p_{\theta}(x_{i-1}\mid x_i)$ starting from $x_0$ and then weight them proportionally to $p_\theta(x_n\mid x_{n-1})$. Asymptotically, this should give the correct distribution (at least intuitively, I haven't checked all details yet).

Does this approach give a good result (for small-ish $L$)? I expect this to be biased in some way (e.g. for $L=1$ we would not be drawing from the correct distribution), is this the case? Are there better approaches I could use to get the unbiased sample I need?

Comment: If anyone can suggest better tags or a better title, I will be happy to update!